# react redux createSlice or createReducer

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

What is the difference between `createSlice` and `createReducer`? Which one I shall use?

I did some research and watched a tutorial today. The tutorial didn't solve my confusion, maybe because it's a bit different from the redux documentation.

The author exported three CONST at the end of the userSlice.js instead of two like in the documention. (I have made a comment)
If I change `state.user.user` to `state.user.<something_else>` I will run into an error after a while because some components do not have access to the user object anymore.

`userSlice.js`

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
        user: null,
    },
    reducers: {
       login: (state, action) => { 
           state.user = action.payload;
       }, 
       logout: (state) => {
           state.user = null;
       },   
    },
});
    
export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;


export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user; 
    
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

in `app.js` he made that command

```js
const user = useSelector(selectUser);
    
// instead 
const user = useSelector(state => state.user.user);
```

I really do nor understand the difference

`store.js` file

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../features/userSlice'
    
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userReducer,
    },
});
```

could somebody please explain this?

Comment: Since you are new to this then you want `createSlice` -- it's the easy way!  A selector function like `selectUser` selects the value from *the whole state*, not just from this slice.  In the `store.js` file this part `reducer: { user: userReducer, }` (called a "reducer map object") means that the whole state is an object with a property `user` that is controlled by the `userReducer`.  So `state.user` gets you the value of the user slice.  But we want the `user` property from that slice, so it's `state.user.user`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Following the first part of your question about [createSlice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) and [createReducer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer):

> I do not know if there is a difference between createSlice and createReducer.

A good source of help is to read the Redux Toolkit docs, where it says:

> createSlice: A function that accepts an initial state, an object full of reducer functions, and a "slice name", and automatically generates action creators and action types that correspond to the reducers and state.

> createReducer: A utility that simplifies creating Redux reducer functions. It uses Immer internally to drastically simplify immutable update logic by writing "mutative" code in your reducers, and supports directly mapping specific action types to case reducer functions that will update the state when that action is dispatched.

An important statement:

> Internally, `createSlice` uses `createAction` and `createReducer`, [...]

You can understand `createSlice` as a function which uses `createReducer` or a helper to bind things up.

About the second part of your question:

```js
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user; // What is that ? and why is it state.user and then a third user Object ???
```

[Selectors](https://medium.com/@matthew.holman/what-is-a-redux-selector-a517acee1fe8) are a very common pattern found when you look into an app using Redux.

> A “selector” is simply a function that accepts Redux state as an argument and returns data that is derived from that state. Bam! The end.

What your selector is doing is accessing your state and get something from there, probably to use inside a React component:

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
const App => () => {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser); 
  return <div>My name is {user.name}</div>
}
```

Comment: thank you but why is it state.user.user and not state.user ( I just do not get the third user variable)

Comment: @danielragimov When they configure the store and create the "root reducer" the user reducer is named "user", i.e. `user: userReducer`, so from the root state it is `state.user.user` to get to the `user` object of the `user` reducer area of state.

Comment: That means I could make the same statement in the story.js file and export it from there Right ?

Comment: Yeah, but I do not see a reason to do so. Selectors, actions and reducer of the same context look better when together.

Comment: I think you should define and organize your selectors where it makes sense for you (your project). The state selector necessarily needs to know the overall state tree structure whereas the reducer/slice does ***not***. Just be aware of this for wherever/however you organize them.

Comment: Ok Last question :). So it is not possible to say const otheruser=useSelector(selectUser) ...... my name is {otheruser.name}

Comment: Yes it is possible, it is a good way to do so.